# File.OpenRead access using UNC path. Impersonation not working?

Tags: asp.net, networking, impersonation, unc

Is there a reason Impersonation does not seem to work with a UNC path using File.OpenRead()?
I'm utilizing [CodeProject's Impersonation utility](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/zetaimpersonator.aspx):

I have a user with rights to the share that I'm passing to OpenRead().

This is my code and it's not accessing the file:

```
try
{
    bool canImp = imp.ImpersonateValidUser(impUser, domain, impPwd);

    FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filePath);
    logger.Debug("File stream opened...");
    byte[] b = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length);
    fs.Close();

    // code continued
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was using the IP address in my impersonation for the domain, rather than the friendly domain name.
Once I used the friendly domain name, the impersonation worked.